# WCF serializing error - 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress' cannot be serialized

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-3.0, mailmessage

Please help me with this WCF error....How do I handle these builtin classes for WCF?

> Type 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress' cannot be serialized. Consider
>   marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all
>   of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute
>   attribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other
>   supported types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a [surrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064.aspx) that knows how to de(serialize) the `MailAddress` type.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class which contains all the data / properties that you need from `MailAddress` to transport across the wire and then map the `MailAddress` to this custom class. You'll need to do the opposite on the client. If you keep the same property names / class hierarchy, a tool like `AutoMapper` could reduce coding in the to / from mapping.